# Retrieve and display blob images from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble trying to display images on a webpage that have been stored in MySQL as MEDIUMBLOB. Other data about the images, such as image size, image type and image name, can be retrieved without problems. This question has probably been posted before but I'm still having trouble after reviewing other posts. Any assistance would be appreciated.

My code is:
($html below is echoed to another page):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY record_id DESC";
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($record_id, $image_name, $image_type, $image_size, $image_content);
    $stmt->store_result();
    if (!$stmt->num_rows) {
        do error check
    } else {
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $html = '<p>Image Name: ".htmlspecialchars($image_name)."<br>Image Type: ".htmlspecialchars($image_type)."<br>
                     Image Size: ".htmlspecialchars($image_size)."</p>'
                     <img src="data:".$image_type.",".$image_content."">';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $image_content ).'"/>';
```

It seems your missing base64